# Duplicate step entries in SSMS Job History Log File Viewer

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sql-server-agent

I'm seeing duplicate entries by Step ID in the SSMS Job History Log File Viewer. This is only happening in one of my jobs. In the duplicates, one is marked as complete, and the other as still running.

[image]

The duplicate running step has a message with a bunch of version trademark information, nothing helpful.

Any ideas on why I'm getting the duplicated steps in this job, and how to get rid of them?

Comment: Anyway you can discover what that warning exclamation is stating at the top of the job tree?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if "Include step output in history" is checked.

Goto your job -> properties -> steps (select one) -> edit -> advanced -> uncheck "include step output in history" if it's there.

Comment: Thanks TEEKAY, that's totally it. Suppose if I want those to go away I just turn off the output. Silly question I suppose. It seems strange that they use a symbol that looks like 'still running'. But hey. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is a behavior of SSMS version 18. They switched the icon from a ribbon to a green "play" icon whenever you check the "Include step output in history" checkbox. That was very confusing to me too! And in my case, the job step with the extra green play icon has nothing useful in the history details either. It simply has the usual header info and then "Message" with nothing after that (in my case it's a step that runs some Powershell code to update AD). It would be nice to have something after message, pertaining to the job step that ran! But there is nothing useful to me. Be well, Raphael.

[image: Differences between SSMS 17.X and SSMS 18.X]